# Powershell scope: variable array within loop not populating when adding to second array

Tags: arrays, variables, powershell, scope

In the following Powershell example, how can I get `$server` to populate within line #5? I'm trying to save the results of a `Get-EventLog` query to an array for each `$server` loop iteration.

Example:

```
$serversArray = @("one", "two", "three")
ForEach ($server in $serversArray) {
  echo $server "Variable array iteration populates here correctly"
  $eventArray = @()
  $eventArray += Get-EventLog -computerName $server #But not here, where I need it
  $eventArray  #Yet it populates from calling the second array correctly
}
```

1. I've tried assigning the scope of the $server variable to global or script.
2. I've researched other similar issues, but none that I could find had this circumstance
3. I've tried different combinations of piping, quotes, back ticks, etc.

As always, thanks in advance.

*Edit* Ok, ISE was caching some of the variables (or something strange), as the above example began working after I restarted ISE. Anyways, the issue is with the `$servers` array input, which in the full script is from a MySQL query. If I statically assign the array with server names (like in the example above) the script works. If I use the input from the MySQL query, `Get-EventLog` fails with `The network path was not found`. So even though the server values look correct (and *something* could be expanding), it could be a text encoding issue, etc. Sorry to waste time, but discussing it has helped narrow it down. Here's the pertinent part of the actual script:

```
#Open SQL Connection
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
$connectionString = "server=dbserver;uid=odbc;pwd=password;database=uptime;"
$connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
#Get server names from db
$sqlGetServers = "select server_nm from servers limit 3;"
$command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($sqlGetServers, $connection)
$dataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($command)
$dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$recordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "sample_data")
$server_names = @()
$server_names += $dataSet.Tables["sample_data"] 
#$server_names = @("server-1","server-2")  <-- this works
#loop through array of server names
foreach($server in $server_names) {
$eventData = @()
$eventData += Get-EventLog -computerName $server -LogName System -Newest 10
foreach($event in $eventdata) {Do-Stuff}
}
```

Comment: I cant reproduce your issue. What version of powershell are you using?

Comment: v3. I've found that the issue is something with the input for `$servers`, which in the actual script are from a MySQL query. I edited the question to include the original script reflecting this.

Comment: Try `$server_names = $dataSet.Tables["sample_data"]` (don't make it an empty array, don't use `+=`. Then run `$server_names | gm` and look at what it is. There's probably a property that you can use (likely the column name) to access the actual string you want.

Comment: @briantist Ok, I finally got it. The data type from the SQL query loses it's formatting when it's passed through the loop. Through your suggestion, I found the property in `$server_names | gm` and used `select`, and it worked:  `$server_names += $dataSet.Tables["sample_data"]| Select -Expand "server_nm"` Thank you again. Choosing your answer below because I still needed to pipe the output of the array to `ForEach-Object` for it to work, which you originally suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not 100% certain what the problem is that you're having. I am assuming that the issue is that your `$eventArray` ends up with just the last result.

If that is correct, then the reason is because you're reinitializing it as empty on every iteration in line 4: `$eventArray = @()`

Try this:

```powershell
$serversArray = @("one", "two", "three")
$eventArray = @()
ForEach ($server in $serversArray) {
  echo $server "Variable array iteration populates here correctly"
  $eventArray += Get-EventLog -computerName $server #But not here, where I need it
  $eventArray  #Yet it populates from calling the second array correctly
}
```

or, alternatively, with `ForEach-Object` like this:

```powershell
$serversArray = @("one", "two", "three")
$eventArray = $serversArray | ForEach-Object {
  echo $_ "Variable array iteration populates here correctly"
  Get-EventLog -computerName $_ #But not here, where I need it
  #Yet it populates from calling the second array correctly
}
```

### Explanation for Method 1:

Declaring `$eventArray` as an empty array *before* the loop starts, then adding items to it within each iteration of the loop, as opposed to initializing it on every iteration.

The way you had it, `$eventArray` would be reset to an empty array every time, and in the end it would just contain the last result.

### Explanation for Method 2:

`ForEach-Object` is a pipeline cmdlet and returns the result of its code block (which is run once **for each object** piped into it.

In this case we use `$_` to represent the individual object. Instead of assigning the result of `Get-EventLog` to `$eventArray`, we simply call it, allowing the return value to be returned from the block.

We assign the entire `ForEach-Object` call into `$eventArray` instead, which will end up with the collection of results from the entire call.

Comment: I wasn't clear on what it wasn't doing. The variable `$server` isn't expanded; it's literally `$server` (or `$_` when using `ForEach-Object`). I see your point about declaring the empty array, but in this case I want to clear the results of the previous server's events before it populates with the next server's results. Thanks.

Comment: And as I mentioned above, this variable will not expand on line 5 with all forms of loops that I have tried here. It must be something specific to array population, because if I call it within the loop but not using `$eventArray +=` it expands correctly.

Comment: Try wrapping it in parentheses like this `$eventArray += (Get-EventLog -computerName $server)` or even wrappin git in `$()` like this: `$eventArray += $(Get-EventLog -computerName $server)`

Comment: Still no dice. Interestingly, the variable `$server` is populating the actual array elements correctly; if I call `$eventArray` after running the above, it outputs the server names. It just that my "array member" in this case is doubling as a command (`Get-EventLog`) and as a means to capture the output (the actual script captures the events queried). I'll look at changing the structure.

Comment: See eventual solution above in comments below original question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead....

```
$serversArray = @("one", "two", "three")
$eventArray = @()
$serversArray | ForEach-Object {
  echo $_ "Variable array iteration populates here correctly"
  $eventArray += Get-EventLog -computerName $_ #But not here, where I need it
  $eventArray  #Yet it populates from calling the second array correctly
}
```

Pipe the array into a for-each loop. then you can use $_

Comment: The other answer then might be more viable. What happened with this answer? Was there and error or was $eventarray not populated?

Comment: Using `ForEach-Object` on the code above still returns the literal `$_` and not the subsitution on line 5. I also tried with the clunkier `for ($i=0; $i -le $serversArray.length-1; $i++)` with the same result. Is there something specific to array population that is preventing this?

Comment: Not that im aware of. Maybe it needs to be $($_) but that just seems silly